# How can I dynamic change separators configuration in Excel 2016 for CSV files?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, microsoft-excel-2016

I've a CSV file opened with Excel. This file use comma separators (`,`) but the default separator for Excel *(with European configuration)* is a semicolon (`;`).

**Note:** I know in America they use a comma separator but in Europe we use a semicolon separator. This we do because a comma is used for a decimal operator.

The Excel developers knows that this is an issue for European CSV files (with `;`) and use also a semicolon because Excel and my computer is European configurated.

The file I'll open is now an American CSV file that uses commas as separator.

My question is how can I dynamic change the separators in Excel 2016 without changing the configuration of my computer every time?

[image]

If I will save the file and I've three options:

- CSV (MS-DOS) (`*.csv`)
- CSV (Macintosh) (`*.csv`)
- CSV (<strike>seperated by list separator stabbing</strike> comma delimited) (`*.csv`)<sup>1</sup>

See image below

<sub><sup>1</sup> In Dutch version and image: *gescheiden door lijstscheidingsteken*. <strike>No idea what this means.</strike></sub>

[image]

I've tried this three options but none will separate the CSV file correct.

**Update 1**

The answer from @Gary's Student is good but the commas are changed again to a semicolon. This is not what I want.

Comment: "CSV (geschijden door lijstscheidingsteken)" is "CSV (comma delimited)" in the English Excel, which I would expect forces it (never actually tested) to save as an actual CSV (Comma Separated) file, regardless of regional format settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to change the Regional Setting at all.  From the Ribbon:

**Data** ->**Get External Data** -> **From Text**

Then tell the Text Import Wizard which separator to use.

Comment: I've unaccepted your answer because every separator is changed again from a comma to a semicolon. This is not what I want to have.